# Randomly sampling rows from pandas dataframe and keeping index

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a very large csv file (4GB), 25 million rows. In order to perform analysis I am looking to take a random sample of about 100,000 rows. I have used the df1 = df.sample(n) function on the data frame.

I find that the index value for df1 is different from the index in the original df. Is there a way to overcome this issue? Does df.sample reset the index in the dataframe it returns?

It is important for me to keep the index because I plan to use it to reference the row in the future.

I have sampled the dataframe in df1. When I try to view the index for one of the elements in the original df, it has a different row associated with it

[image]

Comment: What you're describing contradicts the known behavior of `df.sample(n)`. Therefore I suggest you provide a more concrete example with code. Perhaps a toy example.

Answer (score 1):

`DataFrame.sample` preserves the index.

The issue is with your indexing.`.iloc` allows you to select rows with the counting starting at 0, regardless of the actual Index. From your picture, we can see that the Index of `.iloc[228607]` is really `241545` (From the last line where `Name` is). Likely you dropped some rows in `df` after it was created.

You want to compare with `.loc`, so you can pick out exactly the same row, regardless of where it appears in `df`:

```
df.loc[228607, :]
```